# Hadoop environment variables: when are they initialized?

Tags: hadoop, environment-variables

Using Hortonworks HDP 2.1 (Hadoop 2.40) either using the HDP Sandbox virtual machine or installing a multinodes cluster (CentOS 6.5). Hadoop itself is working OK, all the Java MapReduce programs, Pig, Hive, HBase are working OK.

When I SSH (as root user) to the Hadoop nodes (either masters or slaves), I am surprised that various Hadoop environment variables are not set (HADOOP_HOME, HADOOP_CONF_DIR, HADOOP_xxx, HIVE_HOME, PIG_HOME, etc.)

I suppose these environments variables are set during runtime. When a specific task is executed. Example:

```
# yarn jar MyTestMR.jar MyMRTestClass
```

What is the reason for these Hadoop variables not to be set permanently? Is there any way (and harm?) to make these variable to retain their value? This can help for documentation purpose and easier to remember. For example, HADOOP_LOG_DIR, YARN_LOG_DIR is easier to remember than their physical location (/var/log/ ... something)

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I'm not aware of Hortonworks distribution of hadoop, but in cloudera and apache, there is a hadoop_env.sh file in the conf directory. This file is usually executed before any hadoop related service starts (hdfs, hadoop, yarn, and even the services like namenode datanode executes this sh file before starting.) My guess is horton works should also have a hadoop_env.sh somewhere. I'm sorry if this didn't help for Hortonworks.

Comment: Hi raj, Hortonworks also have hadoop_env.sh. I am checking on every WORKING nodes, i.e Namenode, Datanode, any master or slave services are already started an running. Therefore supposedly the hadoop_env.sh has been called. And yet these HADOOP_xxx vars are not set. I have "su" to some hadoop users such as hdfs, mapred, hive, etc. under the login context of these users, these HADOOP_xxx vars are still empty.

Comment: Do you mean that if you run `sudo hdfs` it throws an error like HADOOP_XX not set?

Comment: I mean if I login as hdfs user (by doing su hdfs), and display the list of environment variables (by set) under the context of that user, there is no HADOOP_xxx variables. For example, if you do echo $HADOOP_HOME, the value is empty.

Comment: Exactly. That is fine. The hadoop_env.sh file do not run as part of login scripts.  try this. Everytime after you login as "hdfs", do a `source /<path>/<to>/hadoop_env.sh`

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-1.6.0.0/bk_using_Ambari_book/content/ambari-chap3-3_2x.html) link, you have to confirm that which account you have used to install HDP. I think in your case you have installed it with another account.

Comment: I installed HDP using the root user. The SSH private key specified for password-less SSH to slave nodes is the one from /root/.ssh/id_rsa. But in case ambari impersonated another user for the installation. How can you know which account was used?

Comment: If your password-less ssh is configured with root then ambari has certainly used it for installation. Now one thing to notice: your environment variables are host specific i.e. if you have installed Hadoop Namenode to a specified host then you will get env variables related to hadoop-hdfs on the same host, not others.